# Webadmin and php are not working correctly

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, mariadb, hyper-v

I have ubuntu server 16.04 running within hyper-v on a Windows 10 computer. I am running LAMP with Apache2, MariaDB, and PHP7.0. I have installed phpmyadmin but when I attempt to call it through my browser I get text, I'm assuming that it is the correct file but it is obviously not outputting the program. These are screenshots of what I'm seeing:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am stuck at this point and have tried doing just about everything. I've entered the Include statement, as well as configured, updated, and upgraded everything. I started out using mysql but MariaDB seems to be working better. I just want to get phpmyadmin up and working and to put my websites up on the internet. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It simply means your PHP interpreter isn't running. Most likely it wasn't installed correctly. Or you might have installed phpmyadmin outside of php's document root, which means php isn't allowed to run the code

Comment: how would I find out what the issue is? I have access to webmin. What would be a good first step to do?

Comment: Go to your document root (something like var/www/ most likely). Create a `info.php` file with the code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. Try to run it in your browser. If it returns a lot of info, it means your php is working fine. If it doesn't, it means your php isn't running at all.

Comment: The file is already there. As such: <?php
phpinfo();
?>

Comment: It will not run. I assume https://192.168.0.230/php.info/

Comment: 192.168.x.y is a local IP address; no one on this side of your router can access it with that address.

Comment: Issue is that your short tag is off in Php INI file. Now u need to use <?Php ?> not <? ?>

Comment: @ Rick James,  I'm still setting up the final parts of the server. I haven't tried transmitting anything beyond locally.

Comment: @ dev pro,  I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: I believe I have turned the short tag on. I have followed the steps in this tutorial from Luis:   https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12177     and used this ppa:    https://launchpad.net/%7Enijel/+archive/ubuntu/phpmyadmin   but now I am getting an error code instead of code. It gives me error 403 You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server. Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.230 Port 443

Comment: I ran install on phpmyadmin and am getting a timed out message now upon accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing everything that is listed, I had rebooted and tried accessing phpmyadmin with success, so I'm at loss for words.